# thread handling

Tags: c, multithreading, exception

Suppose a thread A creates a thread B and after a duration the thread B crashes with an issue, Is there any possibility that the control moves back to the thread A in C language.
Sort of an exceptional handling.

Comment: What then will happen to whatever is being currently executed in thread A?

Comment: there is a reason that sometimes we need multi-process programming instead of multi-thread.

Comment: Maybe a watchdog mechanism between threads

Comment: Seems like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Multithreaded-Programming-Pthreads-Bil-Lewis/dp/0136807291) is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

No. "Control passes back" doesn't make a lot of sense at all, since they are executing independently anyway -- usually, Thread A isn't going to sit around waiting for Thread B to finish, but it will be doing something else.

Incidentally, threads can, of course, check whether another thread is still running. Check your thread library or the system functions that you are using.

However, that will only work for something one could call a "soft crash"; a lot of crashes screw up a lot more than just the thread doing the bad thing, such as hardware exceptions that kill the entire process, or corrupting memory. So, trying to catch crashes in another thread is going to be a good amount of work with little benefit, if any at all. Better spend that time fixing the crashes.

Answer (score 3):

No. They're separate threads of execution. Once thread A has created and started thread B, *both* A and B can execute independently.

Of course if thread B crashes the whole process, thread A won't exist any more...

Answer (score 0):

Threads cannot call other threads, only signal them.  The 'normal' function/method call/return mechanism is stack-based and each thread has its own stack, (it is very common for several threads to run exactly the same code using different stack auto-variables).

If a thread cannot call another thread, then there is no 'return' from one thread to another either.